# Simple Bluetooth Server Raspberry Pi 3(Linux) -- library error

Tags: java, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, bluecove

I have written a simple Java bluetooth server copied from the  example here [digital hacks blog](http://digitalhacksblog.blogspot.ie/2012/05/android-example-bluetooth-simple-spp.html/)... Simple spp server...

I have included the following in my executable  jar

```
    <dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.bluecove</groupId>
  <artifactId>bluecove</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>

  <!-- bluecove-gpl required to run bluecove on Linux-->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.bluecove</groupId>
      <artifactId>bluecove-gpl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.bluecove/bluecove-emu -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.bluecove</groupId>
      <artifactId>bluecove-emu</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

I have installed the following library on my pi

```
apt-get install libbluetooth-dev
```

When i run my app as follows, i get missing library error

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/workspace/bluetooth-server $ java     -jar /tmp/btoothserver-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-    dependencies.jar 
Native Library bluecove_arm not available
Exception in thread "main"     javax.bluetooth.BluetoothStateException: BlueCove L        ibrary bluecove not available
at     com.intel.bluetooth.BlueCoveImpl.loadNativeLibraries(    ... 
...     javax.bluetooth.LocalDevice.getLocalDevice(LocalDevice.java:95)
at com.myapp.bluetoothserver.App.main(App.java:60)
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Looks like you need a library for bluecove, possibly bluez.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, i have all added to my jar as per pom extract above, bluecove, bluecove-gpl and emu (prob not req'd). i also installed libbluetooth-dev on the pi. I'm struggling to see what else i might need...

Comment: Yes you have added the dependencies, but looks like th actual correct lib isn't installed. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34841&p=294901

Comment: @user1843591 did you manage to get it working? I'm stuck on this too!

Comment: hi @PauloPedroso , i'm afraid not. I ended up opting for wi-fi instead. I would be interested in seeing a solution if you manage to get it working.

Comment: I found people who made it work but no answer so far. Will keep you posted. Thanks @user1843591.